# „e“ am Ende eines Wortes einfügen

Tags: meaning, dative, grammar-identification

Ich habe Phrasen wie „das Kind im Manne“ oder „Staat im Staate“ gehört. Ich verstehe zwar die Bedeutung, aber mir fielen jetzt keine andere Beispiele ein oder wie und wann man diese Konstruktion benutzt.
Es wäre sehr nett, wenn jemand das Thema etwas erläutern kann. Also, was heißt das genau (von Bedeutung her und was ist der grammatikalische Name). Außerdem wäre ich für ein paar Beispiele sehr dankbar.

Comment: Siehe auch: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/40750/why-is-there-sometimes-an-e-added-to-a-dativ-noun/40751#40751, obwohl ich mit der Einschätzung es würde fast nicht mehr benutzt nicht so ganz einverstanden bin, wenn es auch selten ist, das Dativ-e.

Comment: Es gibt ziemlich viele ähnliche Fragen, zum Beispiel [diese](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/49840/1696) auf Englisch; die Antwort hat einige weitere Beispiele.

Comment: Eine feste Wendung mit dem Dativ-e ist *Das Kind mit dem Bade ausschütten*, siehe [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/das_Kind_mit_dem_Bade_ausschütten).

Answer (score 13):

Das "e" wird nicht *eingefügt*, sondern *noch nicht weggelassen*.

Der Dativ Singular vieler (maskuliner) Nomen lautet paradigmatisch auf -e: "auf dem Tische", "vor dem Hause" etc. Derzeit ereignet sich aber ein Sprachwandel, so daß die zukünftige Normalform die Form ohne -e sein wird: "auf dem Tisch", "vor dem Haus" etc.

Solcher Sprachwandel geschieht aber nie augenblicklich, sondern immer mit einer Übergangsphase, und nie symmetrisch, sondern immer zuerst an einigen Stellen, dann an den meisten Stellen, schließlich universell.

Feststehende Redewendungen sind meistens die letzten Bastionen der alten Form, eben weil sie feststehen und als Einheit empfunden werden statt als normal flektierter Sprachgebrauch. Ganz besonders resistent sind solche Formen, wenn z.B. ein Reim von der Verwendung der alten Form abhängt.

Das ist hier allerdings nicht der Fall (allenfalls könnte man anführen, daß mit der unbetonten Nachsilbe der Rhythmus des Ausdrucks im Zusammenhang regelmässiger klingt). Deshalb wird bald wohl auch "Das Kind im Mann", "der Staat im Staat" die Normalform und dann die einzige Form werden.

Comment: [Entsprechender Artikel bei duden.de](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Endung-e-im-Dativ-stark-gebeugter-Maskulina-und-Neutra)

Comment: Ich sehe keinen Grund, die Formen ohne *-e* nicht als Normalform anzusehen (wie die Duden-Grammatik es tut). Du hast ja auch nicht *im Zusammenhange* geschrieben.

Comment: *derzeit* war vielleicht vor 50 Jahren richtig....

Comment: Dein Beispiel mit der Tür passt nicht, da weibliche Substantive kein Dativ-e bekommen.